# An Optimal Value of a Diagonal Matrix $\Xi$ in $ H = U \Xi$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

We have access to very accurate estimates of matrices $H$ and $U$ (both are $n \times k$, $n > k$) such that the following relationship holds $$ H = U \Xi$$ where $\Xi$ is a $k \times k$ diagonal matrix. What is the optimal value of $\Xi$ such that the Frobenius norm $\|H-U\Xi\|_{F}$ is minimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h_i$ and $u_i$ ($i=1,\ldots, k$) be the columns of $H$ and $U$, respectively, and $\Xi=\mathrm{diag}(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_k)$. Then
$$\tag{1}
\|H-U\Xi\|_F^2=\sum_{i=1}^k\|h_i-\xi_iu_i\|_2^2.
$$
It is clear that the problem of minimizing (1) over diagonal $\Xi$ decomposes to $k$ independent problems of minimizing $\|h_i-\xi_iu_i\|_2$ over scalars $\xi_i$.

The question is hence: given two vectors $h$ and $u$, find $\xi$ such that $\|h-\xi u\|_2$ is minimal. Assume that $u\neq 0$, otherwise, any (finite) $\xi$ solves the problem. Note that $P:=uu^*/\|u\|_2^2$ is an orthogonal projector onto the span of $u$ and hence $Pu=u$ and $(I-P)u=0$. With 
$$
h-\xi u=\color{red}{P(h-\xi u)}+\color{blue}{(I-P)(h-\xi u)}
=\color{red}{(Ph-\xi u)}+\color{blue}{(I-P)h}.
$$
Since the red and blue terms are mutually orthogonal, the Pythagorean theorem gives
$$
\begin{split}
\|h-\xi u\|_2^2&=\|Ph-\xi u\|_2^2+\|(I-P)h\|_2^2\\&=\|[(u^*h)/\|u\|_2^2-\xi]u\|_2^2+\|(I-P)h\|_2^2
\\&=|\color{green}{(u^*h)/\|u\|_2^2-\xi}|^2\|u\|_2^2+\|(I-P)h\|_2^2.
\end{split}
$$
The second term on the right-hand side is independent of $\xi$, so the minimum is attained when the first term (that is, the green coefficient) is zero and hence when
$$
\xi=\frac{u^*h}{\|u\|_2^2}=\frac{u^*h}{u^*u}.
$$

Comment: thank you. Would the results still hold if all matrices are complex valued (with the transpose replaced by conjugate transpose).

Comment: @Iconoclast Yes, it still holds in the complex case. I've somewhat changed to reasoning to cover this case more easily.